# How can I get pictures from canvas in html with java

Tags: java, html, javafx, web-crawler

I want a crop a picture from https://in-the-sky.org/data/object.php?id=A216

Picture I want to get

[image: Picture I want to get]

I tried Grabzit but I don't get it.  This is the code I tried:

```
public void PlotAction(ActionEvent e) throws Exception
{
    GrabzItClient grabzIt = new GrabzItClient("Sign in to view your Application Key", "Sign in to view your Application Secret");

    // The -1 indicates that image should not be cropped
    ImageOptions options = new ImageOptions();
    options.setBrowserWidth(770);
    options.setBrowserHeight(263);
    options.setFormat(ImageFormat.JPG);
    options.setTargetElement("#chart_div");
    
    grabzIt.URLToImage(url, options);
    grabzIt.SaveTo("result.jpg");
}
```

this is the html code of the picture shown in the site

```
<div class="chart_div" style="padding-top: 0px; overflow: hidden; user-select: auto;"> 
    <div style="user-select: auto;">
        <canvas width="770" height="263" style="user-select: auto;">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

I am wondering how am I supposed to get the picture of canvas and save it as a file.

It doesn't have to be the Grabzit way.

After all what I want to do is show the saved picture on a canvas in javafx.

It would also be thankful if you share a way to show the picture on a new canvas in javafx without saving the picture file.

Comment: JavaFX has a WebView, it can display HTML natively.  You can navigate directly to the in-the-sky page and show it.  If you don't want to display the full interactive page, the page has an export to image button under the image you want.  You could trigger the button to display the image from the WebView either in [Java](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/6722397) or you can [program the webview](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm) JavaScript using [executeScript](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/webview/js-commands.htm#CIHJJIDA).

Comment: If you could get in-the-sky to generate a static URL for the image, then you could just reference that from an Image constructor, but I don't see a way to make the website do that (you could ask the sites creators if they could generate permalinks for the images).

Comment: The site also has an export to csv option, so you could (perhaps) trigger that in the same way (via a WebView executeScript call) to get the data and then render that in a [JavaFX chart](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/charts.htm).  These kinds of hacky things are a bit tricky though if you don't have experience trying them.

Comment: Kind of cute that the [Asteroid in-the-sky](https://in-the-sky.org/data/object.php?id=A216) is named Kleopatra, perhaps it is an alien [Java UI expert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203657/kleopatra).

Comment: Are they 100% sure that is an asteroid. It could be other [object-in-the-sky]  
 (https://images.app.goo.gl/wGWYASwRY3wBf59L7)